# I can't import another script properly (SMTP)

Tags: python, user-interface, smtp

For my application, I'm adding a "report user" feature. In order to avoid a longer code, I aim to report function to be another script. What I'm trying to do is when one user reports another, it will send an email to me. However, when I run the first script below, it just sends me an empty email, not the data I entered on the UI panel.

Main script

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
import reportit 

report_frame = QFrame()
report_frame.setWindowTitle('Report User')
report_box = QFormLayout(report_frame)

rp = QLabel("Enter the user you want to report:",report_frame)
reported_user = QLineEdit(report_frame)
cop = QLabel("Cause of report:",report_frame)
cause_of_report = QTextEdit(report_frame)
report_button_2 = QPushButton("Report the user")

def report():

    target_user = reported_user.text()
    cause = cause_of_report.toPlainText()
    report_text_body = target_user,":", cause
    reportit.send_report(report_text_body)
```

reportit.py

```
import smtplib

def send_report(msg):
     from_addr = "suleymanyamantr@gmail.com"
     to_addr= "suleymanyamantr@gmail.com"
     username = "suleymanyamantr@gmail.com"
     password = "XXXXX"
     server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
     server.ehlo()
     server.starttls()
     server.login(username, password)
     server.sendmail(from_addr, to_addr, str(msg))
     server.quit()
```

Comment: Have you verified that `send_report` is actually receiving the expected data?

Comment: I have just now by setting msg as return value. I believe the problem is SMTP code itself.